# php generate string combinations of missing letters

Tags: php, algorithm

I have some word lets say BKOO.
I need to remove all combinations of missing letters to generate sub words of this initial word. First remove only 1 letter, then n letters to build at least 2 letters words.

So from our example it means to make words like KOO, BOO, OO, BK, BO.

My current algorithm btw says it is possible to generate 7 combinations out of BKOO. (I also include the initial word).

```
Array
(
    [0] => BKOO
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => BKOO
            [1] => KOO
            [2] => OO
            [3] => KO
            [4] => BOO
            [5] => BO
            [6] => BKO
            [7] => BK
        )

)
```

Note there isnt words like BOK or OOK because that would mean do the reorder, but i dont want to do this. I want just leave letters out of current word, and don't do reorder.

Now problem is, this very slow for lenght like 15. It takes forever. How to speed it up?

```
function comb($s, $r = [], $init = false) {
  
  if ($init) {
    $s = mb_strtoupper($s);
    $r[] = $s;
  }
  
  $l = strlen($s);
  if (!$s || $l < 3) return [];
  for ($i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {
      $t = rem_index($s, $i);
      $r[] = $t;
      
      $r = array_merge($r, comb($t));
  }
  $ret = array_unique((array)$r);
  return $init ? array_values($ret) : $ret;
}

// remove character at position
function rem_index($str, $ind)
{ 
   return substr($str,0,$ind++). substr($str,$ind);
}

$s = 'BKOO';
print_r(comb($s, [], true));
```

https://www.tehplayground.com/62pjCAs70j7qpLJj

**NERD SECTION:**

Interesting note - first i thought i will generate array of some dropping indexes eg, first drop only 1 letter so say drop 0 then 1 etc etc, then 2-combinations so drop 1 and 2, 1 and 3 etc, but then i thought it would be quite difficult to drop N letters out of string at once, so i came with idea that i always drop some letter from the string, and recursively call the function again if you get me, so the next level is one char dropped already and does the drop iteration again. Problem is it is very slow for some reason.

Btw if you have also the math background, what is equation to compute the resulting combinations? To me the rough computation is lets say for 15 letters word 14 * 13 * 12 or at least it does such iteration, but that would be milions of combinations and obviously its not like that even for shorter words like 8.

Thanks.

Comment: You may find more help on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as it's more designed for help with optimising working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the string to get it.

```
function foo(&$res,$str,$min_length){

    if(strlen($str) <= $min_length){
        return;
    }

    $remains=[];
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++){
        $remain = substr($str,0,$i) . substr($str,$i+1);
        if(!isset($res[$remain])) {             // only process unprocessed sub string
            $res[$remain] = $remain;
            $remains[] = $remain;
        }
    }

    foreach($remains as $remain){
        if(strlen($remain) == $min_length){
            $res[$remain] = $remain;
        }else {
            foo($res, $remain, $min_length);
        }
    }
    return;
}
$str = "BKOO";
$res = [];
foo($res,$str,2);
var_dump(array_values($res));
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation of how this works and is an improvement over OP's code.

Comment: some note added.

Comment: can you explain why is your code faster, is it reference in arguments or

Comment: i can send you dogecoins in value $10 for the answer if you give me your address, then you can delete the comment with address i hope later

Comment: @LF00 thanks you can remove the address, tell me later if you wil get the donate. i sent it now.

Comment: thank you. I need some time to sync the data.When it done, I'll notice you.

Comment: @luky Is there a light wallet without sync the block, then can see the translation and balance. What wallet are you use. I've tried dogecoincore and multidoge, they both have to sync very large data. Days has passed, and the sync work is not finished.

Comment: @LF00 Hi, i am using Trust wallet on iPhone. I can't guarantee it is a trust worthy wallet but i am using it now. It supports multiple cryptos. As primary wallet i use Blockchain wallet but that doesn't support that much crypto counts as Trust wallet. Also in Trust wallet you can do swaps using Decentralized services to another coins unlike in Blockchain wallet. Problem is, if you download Trust wallet now, you won't be most likely able to recreate your original doge wallet there. The transfers there are within minutes btw.

Comment: @luky thank you, I've finished the sync work, and see the 65 Doge coins.

Comment: @LF00 you are welcome thanks too. why is your code faster, because it uses array as reference and the functions array_merge etc are too slow?